# How to update python package in a docker?

Tags: docker

I have an internal docker in the  repository which I need to upgrade the version of one of python package (`scikit-learn`).

I don't have the `.Dockerfile` which this docker created from.

How can I upgrade the version of python package (in my case scikit-learn package) in existing docker ?

Comment: You can build your own image `FROM` the image you have and `pip install` the newer library, but it will always be larger than the original image (potentially much larger if the original image didn't include build tools).  It'd be better to find the original image's Dockerfile if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: This is a pragmatic solution for your problem, however obviously it would be better if you had access to the original Dockerfile.

- First ssh into the running docker container (assuming it has bash, otherwise use /bin/sh):

```
docker exec -it <container-id> /bin/bash
```

- Then do your magic to update the package inside the container (I assume you know how to do it).
- Then [commit](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/#examples) the updated container as an image. This will create a new image from the state of your container.

```
docker commit <container-id> <tag>
```

- If you want you could then push the updated image into the repository if you need to.

Comment: `docker commit` is not really a best practice at all.  Say the image the question is starting from takes an update, but doesn't update the `sklearn` version; will you remember in a year how you did these manual steps?

Comment: I personally agree and added a disclaimer at the end. However in some cases is no other way unfortunately.